# I have problems with localstorage

Tags: javascript

I have a script that generates 400 localstorage strings:

```
for(i=1;i<401;i++){
  localStorage.setItem(i,'empty');
}
```

This works.
And I have a script that should read this data:

```
for(i=1;i<401;i++){
    console.log(localStorage.getItem(i));
    ...
}
```

When I run it, it logs only 23 times instead of 400. What's the problem?

Comment: it is working perfectly, give some more code.

Comment: That code should just work fine as intended. There might be some other places that is removing the stored value. To confirm, you can copy and paste both the set and get code (for loop) in your browser console and check the result in console.

Comment: Works for me as well.

Comment: Thank you Ankit, in the console it works. I should check my code again ;)

Comment: @Manuxx cool. Whenever you have such JavaScript you can test them in the browser console. As easy as that to debug.